# PHP Edit/Delete multiple rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening, I'm trying to make a single php page wich can edit/delete multiple rows in mysql:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Update/Delete Test Page</title>  
</head>  
<body> 

<?  
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['edit'])) // from button name="delete"
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) {
        $ed = $check;
        $sql = "UPDATE events SET title = '$title', description ='$description' WHERE id = $ed";  
    }
    }

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
}
    ?>

<?php
include ("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) // from button name="delete"
{
    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) {
        $del = $check;

        $sql = "DELETE from events where id = $del";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
}
?>  

<?php
include 'connect.php';
$query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM events WHERE evdate = "1/9/2013" order by title asc';
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

echo '<br><br><br>';
echo '<b><div align="center"> "1/9/2013"</div></b>';

if ($result2) {

  // create a new form and then put the results
  // into a table.
  echo "<form method='post' action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">"; 
  echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
    <th align='left'>Interval orar</th>
    <th align='left'>Eveniment</th>
    <th align='left'></th>
    ";

  while ($row = $result2->fetch_object()) {

    $title  = $row->title;
    $description = $row->description;
    $id     = $row->id;

    //put each record into a new table row with a checkbox
echo "
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><input type='text' name='title' size='20'  value='$title'></td>
        <td align='left'><input type='text' name='description' size='50'  value='$description'></td>
        <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]'  value=$id />
     </tr>

     "; 
}

// when the loop is complete, close off the list.
echo "</table>
<p>
<input id='edit' type='submit' class='button' name='edit' value='Edit'/> 
<input id='delete' type='submit' class='button' name='delete' value='Delete'/>
</p>
</form>";
}   
?>
</body>  
</html>
```

Connect.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "calendar";
$db_pass = "calendar";
$db_name = "ecalendar";
$con = mysql_connect ("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to     mysql database");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

$mysqli = new MySQLi($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

The delete works fine, but the edit doesn't do anything...

Table looks like this:

```
Start/End Time         Event     (Checkbox is here)
08:00-10:00            test1               X
10:00-12:00            test2               X
```

When I try to edit test2 to test2xx I get this in Firebug POST :

```
title=08%3A00-10%3A00&description=test1&title=10%3A00-12%3A00&description=test2xx&checkbox%5B%5D=53&edit=Edit
```

If I delete I get this (and it works)

```
title=08%3A00-10%3A00&description=test1&title=10%3A00-12%3A00&description=test2&checkbox%5B%5D=53&delete=Delete
```

Edit works but only for the last row (test2), if I try to edit the row above (test1), it insted updates it with the values of the last row (test2)

Comment: why you using a for loop for check box array? try to use a foreach loop eg: foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $rows){  }

Comment: same thing with foreach...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

gave up on the code above and went with this example from

```
http://bohemiawebsites.com/PHP-MYSQL-Update-Multiple-Rows.html
```

Everything works if anybody needs it...

Answer (score 3):

Guess you need `del_id` not `id`

```
$sql = "UPDATE events SET title = '$title', description ='$description' WHERE id = $del_id ";
```

Comment: Yes it seems the problem is because of this!

Comment: do you get the $_POST['checkbox'] correctly ? or you got any error?

Comment: Finaly it gave me some errors. I seem to be missing 2 }} for for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++) and if(isset($_POST['edit']))

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, I forgot to check the box. It works now. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

1-look your value `value=$id` in your chekbob

change it to `value= '$id'`

2-and also , the delete query is with mysqli 
but the update query is with mysql ??

3- u dont have to include connect.php 3 times

4- also what previous answer about the variable `$del_id`.

5- u are missing closing tag `td`

6- u are missing closing `}`

7- try this

```
<html>  
 <head>  
 <title>Update/Delete Test Page</title>  
 </head>  
 <body> 

 <?php  
 include 'connect.php';

 if(isset($_POST['edit'])) // from button name="edit"
 {
 $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
 $countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);

 for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++)
 {
    $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];

  $sql3 = "UPDATE events SET title = '$title', description ='$description' WHERE id = '$del_id' ";  
  $result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
 if (!$result3)
 {
 die(mysqli_error($mysqli)) ;
 }
 echo "1 record added";

 }
 }



  if(isset($_POST['delete'])) // from button name="delete"
 {
 $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
 $countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);

 for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++)
 {
    $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];

    $sql = "DELETE from events where id = '$del_id' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

  }
  }


  $query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM events WHERE evdate = "1/9/2013" order by title asc';
  $result2 = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

  echo '<br><br><br>';
  echo '<b><div align="center"> "1/9/2013"</div></b>';

 if ($result2) {

 // create a new form and then put the results
 // into a table.
 echo "<form method='post' action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">"; 
 echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
 <th align='left'>Interval orar</th>
 <th align='left'>Eveniment</th>
 <th align='left'></th>
 ";

 while ($row = $result2->fetch_object()) {

 $title  = $row->title;
 $description = $row->description;
 $id     = $row->id;

  //put each record into a new table row with a checkbox
 echo "
 <tr>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='title' size='20'  value='$title'></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='description' size='50'    value='$description'></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]'  value='$id' /></td>
  </tr>

 "; 
 }

 // when the loop is complete, close off the list.
 echo "</table>
 <p>
 <input id='edit' type='submit' class='button' name='edit' value='Edit'/> 
  <input id='delete' type='submit' class='button' name='delete' value='Delete'/>
  </p>
 </form>";
 }   
 ?>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: is not helpful my answer ?

Comment: missed closing } for if(isset($_POST['edit'])). If I try to edit it gives me  Undefined variable: title in test.php on line 19 and Undefined variable: description in test.php on line 19, and it leaves the boxes empty

Comment: Undefined variable: result2 in test.php on line 9

Comment: I did the same thing (moved that on top). It does the same thing, it copies the last rows values to the one above

Comment: what same thing i dont understand what u want exactly , must go out now and back in one hour. u can explain me what u want . and i will see it

Comment: I use xampp wich has Apache 2.4.3, MySQL 5.5.27 and PHP 5.4.7, if it's at all relevant...

Comment: I made a calendar with events. I need a table wich contains the events from a day. I need to be able to modify the title(start-end time)or description (eg. test, test2) or delete any event. Now the delete part works, I can delete any event (in any order) or multiple events at the same time. I cannot edit the values (title or description) of the rows except the last one. If I try to modify any value (except the last row) it copies the values of the last row to the row above and I get duplicates in the event list.

Comment: Right now I'm securing my pages with an admin login. This edit/delete thing is the last thing I have to do...

Comment: maybe I should start from scratch

Comment: ohh sorry look this code `and isset($_POST['checkbox[]']) )` just remove the `[]` in line 10 and 32 , this should work

Comment: I also have wamp and Ampps, I will try the code with them. Maybe its something with xampp...

Comment: Same thing, I can edit the last row in the list but not the ones above

Comment: sorry maybe u gave little code , u better share ur code and i will see whats wrong.

Comment: Tried the code in wamp and ampps and it i can't edit except the last row

Comment: not the connect.php , i mean the current file is not complet , are u using many checkboxs ??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9BcRYvPN the page I am curently using. I can delete but not edit (except the last row). I only have 2 things in the database for 1/11/2013 http://s9.postimage.org/og5jdqm0f/editdel.png

Comment: If I edit test2 to something else (eg. test1), the page refreshes and test2 becomes test2xx and start/end time changes to 12:00-14:00. The values of the last row are copyed to the row above

Answer (score 0):

id=$del_id under for loop,double check your SQL statements and variables bound to them.

Comment: I corrected everything and it works but only if I edit the last row (test2). If I try to edit one of the rows above (test1) they are updated with the values of the last line (test2).